# Unable to play HLS live or VOD stream on chromecast from chrome sender app

Tags: apache, google-chrome, chromecast, http-live-streaming

My setup:

- XAMPP (version 5.6.20)
- using source code: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome
- Google Chrome (Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit))
- Macbook air (10.11.1 (15B42))
- Chromecast 2nd generation (firmware version: 1.18.55065)

Modified httpd.conf located here: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
.....
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
</Directory>
```

and later in httpd.conf made sure this is enabled:

```
 LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

If I do where castvideo is the same path as the root of https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome:
`curl -I https://myserver.com/castvideo/index.html`

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 23:12:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.6.20 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3323
Content-Type: text/html
```

When I click the "Load Custom Media" button to load https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8, get this error from chromecast logs from http://RECEIVER-IP-ADDRESS:9222:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load     https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.gstatic.com' is therefore not allowed access.
media_player.js:22  [ 23.204s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8 0]
media_player.js:22  [ 23.212s] [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/311Gb @ media_player.js:22Eb.di @ media_player.js:22ib.log @ media_player.js:19Kb @ media_player.js:23L @ media_player.js:85xg.Ub @ media_player.js:166k.fd @ media_player.js:108of.fd @ media_player.js:109k.uc @ media_player.js:108pc @ media_player.js:34oc.dispatchEvent @ media_player.js:33Gc @ media_player.js:39Ic @ media_player.js:42D.Ui @ media_player.js:40D.zh @ media_player.js:40
media_player.js:22  [ 23.216s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload
cast_receiver.js:45  [ 23.376s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error: [object Object]
```

**Question:**

Why cannot I not play a HLS stream?

Why am I getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."? When I do a curl it shows it is present.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Google Developer site provide easy way to remember global link of permission. If you want to make cross origin requests, you can add `permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` to the manifest or else you can use matching patterns which is described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Here's a sample project which uses HLS player: https://github.com/RReverser/mpegts

Comment: what would i configure for a chromecast sender app? (developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender)